# How can i override the luma theme category page stylings in new custom theme?

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, custom-theme

We have to override the luma theme stylings of the category page,we have applied pearl theme on top of it.And we are extending same for custom child theme.

How can i override the default luma css for it?

Answer (score 0):

To override the functionality you just need to copy and paste that less file in web/css ( following module directory structure,like Magento_Catalog/web/css/ ) folder and make changes what you want.

Then you need to deploy static content.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new custom css in :

> app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/web/css/new-style.css

```
.your-css {
    ...
}
```

You declare your `new-style.css` in :

> app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/new-style.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Don't forget to clean `static-content`, and `cache`.